# The image is not being posted to api in ionic

Tags: image, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on the ionic application which uses POST API. And I am feeding that POST API with an image/blob but not taking that image into it. If the api took the image then it'll will return a string as an output and it should be visible in the HomePage in **ionic**.

Here is the code.

```
givetoapi(){
  var uploadingImage = new Image();
  uploadingImage.src = "../assets/imgs/banana.jpg";
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('content-type','image/*');
  let url = 'http://af46cff3.ngrok.io';
  let postData = JSON.stringify({
    key :'predimg',
    value :uploadingImage.src
  })
  let data:Observable<any> = this.http.post(url,postData)
  data.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert image to data first before uploading to server follow this tutorial https://www.djamware.com/post/5ae9c9ca80aca714d19d5b9f/ionic-3-angular-5-and-cordova-base64-image-upload-example

Comment: fileTransfer.upload('your imagetest.png', 'http://someserver', options) .then((data) => { console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully"); }, (err) => { console.log(err); });